# JPA : insert and delete object in same transaction

Tags: java, jpa

I want to insert an object into database in a transaction and after that object is saved in the database, I'd like to delete that it once a specific operation is done. Can I restart the transaction again and perform deletion and then commit? Is this a correct way of doing it?

Example :

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
String name = "Ronnie";
entityManager.getTransaction.begin();
employee.setName(name);
entityManager.persist(employee);
entityManager.getTransaction.commit();

//After few steps

entityManager.getTransaction.begin();
entityManager.remove(employee);
entityManager.getTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But, why persist it if you're gonna delete it after that?

Comment: I want to store it temporarily. Like I don't need it anymore after a few specific processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:** Yes, you can do that whithout problems.

**LONG ANSWER:** Yes, you can.
Every transaction is independent of any other transaction. So, if you do some operations, commit them (remember, committing a transaction execs the operations in the DB, and closes it), and then reopen it lately, it is independent of the last transaction.
You can even be in the same transaction, whithout closing it, by flushing changes to the DB:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
String name = "Ronnie";
entityManager.getTransaction.begin();
employee.setName(name);
entityManager.persist(employee);
entityManager.flush();

//After few steps, the transaction is still the same
entityManager.remove(employee);
entityManager.getTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The transaction isolate database state from other transactions. So you can insert and delete in the same transaction. no need to commit it.

Comment: I didn't get this. Can you elaborate this?

Comment: while being in the same transaction you can insert and select the inserted row even if you did not commit it