# Persisting and removing an entity in the same transaction

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

With a setup similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689950/jpa-insert-and-delete-object-in-same-transaction), I'm considering the situation where an entity is persisted and then removed in the same transaction. Does EclipseLink optimize that by not persisting the entity in the DB (i.e. not running an insert and then a delete query)?

Comment: Try it! Answer is that it entirely depends on your situation. If you flush/commit or force it to, JPA will push the state of the persistence unit as it is in that moment, so you may get insert/delete statements. Generally if you remove and persist or persist and remove something, EclipseLink will cancel out the operations - it only issues statements it needs to when it is required to (via flush/commit or query flush settings).